# How to calculate Integral with sinusoidal term have rational power?

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate this integral

$$\int\frac{{\sin x}dx}{\sqrt{a-b\sin x}}$$

where $a \geq b$

If i assume that $ a \gt \gt b $ then approximately i can calculate this through binomial expression but is there any exact solution of this integral?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%28x%29+%2F+sqrt%28a-b+sin%28x%29%29+dx) offers a solution, but it doesn't use elementary functions. Namely it makes references to elliptic integrals of the first and second kinds. So I doubt there is a nice, closed-form solution.

Answer (score 1):

As  Eevee Trainer commented, assuming $a - b \sin(x) > 0\,\, \forall x$ and $a >b$, you get as a result
$$I=\int\frac{{\sin (x)}}{\sqrt{a-b\sin (x)}}\, dx=\frac{2 \left((a-b) E\left(\frac{\pi -2 x}{4} |-\frac{2 b}{a-b}\right)-a
   F\left(\frac{\pi -2 x}{4} |-\frac{2 b}{a-b}\right)\right)}{b \sqrt{a-b}}$$ where appear elliptic integrals of the first and second kind; this cannot reduce to any elementary functions.

For sure, if $a \gg b$, just as you wrote, using $k=\frac ba$, you can write
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b\sin (x)}}=\frac 1 {\sqrt a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k\sin (x)}}=\frac 1 {\sqrt a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} k^n \sin ^n(x)$$ to make
$$I=\frac 1 {\sqrt a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} k^n \int\sin ^{n+1}(x)\,dx$$ and use the reduction formula for the remaining integral.

Answer (score 0):

It is an elliptic integral.

It does not have exact anti derivatives in term of elementary functions.